# Limit the image size on laravel request post

Tags: php, laravel, post, request

Hello guys I need to limit the size of the image, not the size of file, but the width and height, so far I have this:

```
public function rules()
{
    if(request()->isMethod('put')) // could be patch as well
    {
         // Update rules here - Don't require image here
         return [
            'name' =>                'required',           
            'code' =>                'required|regex:/^#?(([a-f0-9]{3}){1,2})$/i',
            'image' =>               'required|image|max:8192',
        ];

    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you're looking for the [dimensions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-dimensions) validation rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible

```
'image' => 'required|image|dimensions:max_width=300,max_height=300'
```

As document says

> The file under validation must be an image meeting the dimension
> constraints as specified by the rule's parameters:
>
> 'avatar' => 'dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=200'

> Available constraints are: min_width, max_width, min_height,  max_height, width,
> height, ratio.

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-dimensions